# Enabling Async file uploads with jQuery File Upload + Carrierwave + Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to allow users to move around the portal when the file uploads are happening.

This is my form code:

```
<%= form_for [@myfolder, Myfile.new], html: { multipart: true, :id => "fileupload" }, :remote => true, do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :attachment, multiple: true, style: "display:none;" %>
<% end %>
```

It is hitting the create action (POST), which is responding with the JSON output.

```
format.html { redirect_to @parentfolder, notice: 'Your file was successfully created.' }
format.js
format.json{ render :show, status: :created, location: @myfile }
```

Here's the jquery file uploads call in my application.js:

```
add: function(e, data) {
     data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload",data.files[0]))
     $('#fileupload').append(data.context)
     $('#inline-upload-status').show();
     $.getJSON('/myfiles.json', function (result) {
        data.formData = result; // e.g. {id: 123}
        data.submit();
     });
  }
```

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with this code. The file uploads are not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this gem [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).

Comment: I'm yet to try remotipart. The reason being, even remotipart uses the iframe Transport jQuery, which is included in the jQuery File Upload plugin already.

Comment: Yes it does, but the idea is that it will solve the JS problems and you will only have to add remote: true in your form and then carry one with your other tasks.